# Criar tuplas de dataframe gerado pelo Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

É possível gerar uma tupla que armazene os valores das linhas de um dataframe gerado pelo pandas? Carreguei os valores de um arquivo CSV para um dataframe, agora preciso realizar alguns cálculos com esses valores, mas não encontrei dicas na internet. Agradeço.

Por exemplo: tupla = "valorA","valorB".

Onde **tupla** é o **nome da coluna**.

**valorA** é o valor contido na **primeira linha desta coluna**.

**valorB** é o calor contido na **segunda linha desta coluna**.

E assim sucessivamente **enquanto houver linhas no dataframe**.

```
 import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv("TESTE.CSV", sep=",",header=None,usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],engine="python")

    print (df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde

Você consegue fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
```

Para você pegas as tuplas por coluna seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
colunas = df.columns.values
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in [df[coluna].values for coluna in colunas]]
```

Comment: Opa, tudo certo? Assim eu armazeno todos os valores do df, certo? Tem como criar uma tupla para cada coluna?

Comment: Certo, assim ele armazena todos os dados da coluna no endereço 0 da tupla. Tem como armazenar os dados da coluna em endereços diferentes? por exemplo: tupla[0] contém o dado da linha 0, tupla[1] contém o dado da linha 1 e assim sucessivamente até terminar a coluna.

Comment: Na verdade a estrutura das tuplas é a seguinte: `tuples[coluna][linha]`, por exemplo tuples[0][1] vai retornar o valor da linha 1 e coluna 0, o valor de tuples[1][1] vai retornar o valor de linha 1 e coluna 1 e tuples[0][3] vai retornar o valor de linha 3 e coluna 0

Comment: Certo, me ajudou muito! Obrigado brow-joe!!!